# intent error to change activity

Tags: android, crash

I have v=created an application of setting wallpaper but it crashes all the time when user opens the next category. When user want to set another wallpaper and go to one to another category application is crashed. Any one knows the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

You dont specify which extension image you are used if you are used jpeg some problems are there use .png extension image into your project.. May be its work..

Comment: Convrt it into .png extension....Bcz Some high resolution not support in your avd manager.. if you use into your mobile device may be its work...there were a some rules and regulation if you used .png thats a better way..

Comment: In avd it works. But does not work in phones. As i have published my app on play store and i got 4 reports of crashes of this kind of error. (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
in android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate)